# remove file with -h_some_file_name in shell

Tags: command-line, files, rm

I have a problem when trying removing a file with name something like `-h_some_file_name`, this is because of generated script that I made and forget to check the prefix.

If I run the command `rm '-h_some_file_name'` it return an error `rm: invalid option -- 'h'`.

If I try to change the name and then remove it using `mv '-h_some_file_name' new_filename` it return `mv: invalid option -- 'h'`

**Question:**
How to remove a file with name like `-h_some_file_name` in shell? if using gui I can right click and move to trash, but in shell only returns an error

Comment: Try using double quotes instead of single.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
rm -- -h_some_file_name
```

Or:

```
rm ./-h_some_file_name
```

See the manpage of `rm`:

```
   To remove a file whose name starts with a `-', for example `-foo', use one of these
   commands:

          rm -- -foo

          rm ./-foo
```

The `--` argument tells `rm` that all following argument should not be treated as parameters. A variety of other Linux/Unix command line tools support that argument. This interpretation of `--` follows the POSIX argument parsing conventions<sup>1)</sup>. The `mv` utility also supports it:

```
mv -- -h_some_file_name new_file_name
```

---

<sup>1) [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, IEEE Std 1003.1, Guideline 10](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards.
Here in this case you can use '*' wildcard.

Go to the directory where files of this type is to be deleted or you need to mention the complete path in the command.

After setting to the terminal prompt to your directory, type in the following

```
rm ./-h*
```

For little bit more information you can see this link: http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm

For indepth information follow some book related to bash.